# iPhone - Strike out an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uifont

I would like to know if there is an easy way to strike/cross out some text on the iPhone?

Thanks

Comment: With UILabel, or drawing NSString in `-drawRect:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and No,

NSString is a simple class, that only stores unformated text, but you can use an NSAttributedString to store such information, i.e.

```
NSAttributedString* italicText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myNsString attributes:myCrossOutAttributes];
```

Comment: Note: NSAttributedString is available only since ≥3.2.

Comment: shoot... If I develop for 3.0 I can't strike out?

Comment: Nope, not using NSAttributedString. You could however subclass UILabel and add some custom drawing code in -drawRect:, like KennyTM said.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are correct and that leaves us with a "No, it is not easy" as an answer. ):

Comment: Someone could help me for the hard solution?

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *strikeThroughString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:anyString];
[strikeThroughString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:(NSNumber *)kCFBooleanTrue range:NSMakeRange(0, [as length])];
[m_cObjTaskTitle setAttributedText:strikeThroughString =];
cObjTaskTitle = UILabel ;
```